# Datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timestamp

I have a column in table which is showing `last_updated_date`. Currently it is in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format and I want it in `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss` format.

Datatype of the column is `datetime`.

Comment: Datetime columns do not store datetimes with a display format, they store them in a binary format. You UI displays them, so you need to explain what UI you are using? And if you wish to do this formatting in SQL there are a bunch of functions which you can use - all easy to find in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This code gets you date

```
select FORMAT(last_updated_date,'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss ') as last_updated_date from table_name
```

For different formats please refer

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2655/format-sql-server-dates-with-format-function/

Comment: Although format performs badly, so convert is preferred.